# problem with using axios in laravel project

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios

I'm using axios to make a live laravel project and get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: axios is not defined`.

I imported `app.js` in my view component like this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

<script>
(function() {
    const options = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity')

    Array.from(options).forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('change', function() {
            const id = element.getAttribute('data-id')

            axios.patch(`/cart/${id}`, {
                quantity: this.value
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        })
    });
})();
```

I believe the first script tag is causing the issue because I get this error in the console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

However, I don't know how to link to `app.js` file properly.

Comment: Did you run `npm run install && npm run dev`?

Comment: I did. `npm run install` returns an error saying that the command doesn't exist and `npm run dev` made a local host. neither fixed the issue.

Comment: Just run ``npm install`` then you can also run ``npm run dev`` you do not ``npm run install`` it's just npm install

Comment: They're using laravel, a php framework. It probably doesn't come with a javascript bundler

Comment: @Samathingamajig what if one use laravel with breeze ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze

Comment: Do you have app.js here /public/js/app.js?

Comment: my app.js is in resources/js/app.js

Comment: @EricSsSnake Stack Overflow pages must never be "resolved" by editing the question.  If you have found a resolution for your task, please post an answer.  Please "rollback" your last edit after posting your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved after I ran npm install npm install vite npm run dev and added this line to my view file up in the head tag:

```
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
```